# bar z-index for ggplot2 geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created the following graphic ggplot

[image]

with the following code;

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=100*prop_select, y=(1500-s_meanResponse), fill=product)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity', width=2,  alpha=.6, color='#333333') + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 5)) +
  coord_flip()

print(p)
```

I am attempting to intentionally overlap the bars. I would like to know how to change the z-index (depth) of each of the bars. I attempted to do this by simply reordering the levels of the factor column that determines my bars

```
# Order by mean response to make sure that bars are layered correctly (does not work!)
# Switching this minus makes no difference to the bar z-index but does reverse legend entries
df <- df[sort.list(-df$s_meanResponse),] 
df$product <- factor(df$product, levels=df$product)
```

Anybody know if this is possible with ggplot2?

EDIT:

dataframe is structured similar to below

```
df <- data.frame( product=c('a','b','c'), s_meanResponse=c(1120,1421,1320), prop_select=c(.3,.2,.5))
```

Comment: Please include a sample of `df`.

Comment: Would you consider using a scatter point with labelled points instead? For the bar chart, you could see if `levels=rev(df$product)` works in the `factor()` expression.

Comment: Tried reordering the levels to no effect. A scatter plot is the natural choice for such data however I am stuck with attempting this type of visualisaton - clients eh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using the following df with actual overlapping:

```
df <- data.frame(product=c('a','b','c'), 
                 s_meanResponse=c(1120,1421,1320), 
                 prop_select=c(.311,.32,.329))
```

It seems that the plotting order remains the same regardless of the factor levels ordering, instead it just plots bars from lowest to highest y-value. To achieve custom ordering, we'll have to do the following, plotting layers explicitly one by one in the desired order:

```
geom_bars_with_order <- function(vals)
{
  l <- list()
  for (i in vals) 
  {
    l <- c(l, geom_bar(data = df[df$product == i, ], 
                       stat='identity', width=2, alpha=.6, color='#333333'))  
  }
  l
}
# default order
ggplot(NULL, aes(x=100*prop_select, y=(1500-s_meanResponse), fill=product)) + 
  geom_bars_with_order(c("a", "b", "c")) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 5)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

```
# custom order, "a" on top
ggplot(NULL, aes(x=100*prop_select, y=(1500-s_meanResponse), fill=product)) + 
  geom_bars_with_order(c("b", "c", "a")) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 5)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: bravo! I knew a ggplot ninja would come to the rescue at some point! Thanks 1,000,000!

Comment: Also, Apologies for not providing example data that overlapped!